# What is the equivalent of this function in Javascript/NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, encryption, openssl

This is the function used to encrypt in php

```
function generatetoken()
{
    $token = ['id' => '123456','name' => 'username','email' => 'useremail@example.com','type' => 'user'];
    $cipher = "AES-128-CBC";
    $plaintext = json_encode($token);
    $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher = "AES-128-CBC");
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
    $ciphertext_raw = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $cipher, '123456789', $options = OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    $hmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $ciphertext_raw, '123456789', $as_binary = true);
    $ciphertext = base64_encode($iv . $hmac . $ciphertext_raw);       
    return ciphertext;
}
```

I have this function to decrypt text in php :

```
function decodetokeninPhp($request_token)
{
    $cipher = "AES-128-CBC";
    $c = base64_decode($request_token);
    $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher = "AES-128-CBC");
    $iv = substr($c, 0, $ivlen);
    $hmac = substr($c, $ivlen, $sha2len = 32);
    $ciphertext_raw = substr($c, $ivlen + $sha2len);
    $original_plaintext = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext_raw, $cipher, '123456789', $options = OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    $calcmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $ciphertext_raw, '123456789', $as_binary = true);
    if (hash_equals($hmac, $calcmac)) {
      return json_encode($original_plaintext);
    } else {
       return null;
    }
}
```

I want the equivalent of this in javascript/Nodejs, i tried this:

```
function decode(token){
var password = 'My-key';
const ivLength = 16;
const sha2len = 32;
let replacedToken = token.toString();
const base64decoded = Buffer.from(replacedToken, 'base64').toString('binary');
const iv = replacedToken.substr(0,ivLength);
const hMac= replacedToken.substr( ivLength,sha2len);
const ciphertext_raw = replacedToken.substr(ivLength+sha2len);

var DataEncrypt = ciphertext_raw;
var DataKey = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(password);
var DataVector = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(iv);
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(DataEncrypt, DataKey, { iv: DataVector });        
var decrypted = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(JSON.stringify(decrypted));
console.log("token decoded"+ decrypted);
}
```

But the console.log just print "token decoded:",  it's empty result :(

Please someone help me i'm going crazy  :/

Comment: Have you logged any previous values to detect where it becomes empty?

Comment: Why are you initializing some varaibles with `var`? You can change all of them to `let` or even `const` if you are not reassigning

Comment: @El_Vanja yes, in this line the result became empty  :                                                               var decrypted = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(JSON.stringify(decrypted));

Comment: @adiga   yes you are right i'll change this, for now i just wnat to make this work , i'm going crazy with this  :/

Comment: Ok, so what is the value of `decrypted` before you feed it to that line?

Comment: @El_Vanja  just before that line the value is like this: {
  words: [
      132582710,  2065704965,  1166352654,   780798850,
...  ],
  sigBytes: 28
}

Comment: Can you please include the full value in the question, so that we can test it? And also include what your desired result is (or better yet, supply the value of the token, so that we can run the PHP code and see for ourselves).

Comment: @El_Vanja   i've added the function to generate de token too, i made it's less complex to be easy to understand what i'm trying to do. If you can help me  :/

Comment: In NodeJS the crypto module is available, why don't you use that? CryptoJS is also possible, but this works internally with WordArrays. Which library do you prefer?

Comment: @Topaco  Thanks for your time, i prefer the crypto because he's internal and no extern depencende is needed, but  can be any of then, i just want to make this  works :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the crypto module of NodeJS, the whole CryptoJS part has to be changed. A possible implementation with crypto is:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

function decode(token){

    var keyDec = Buffer.from('0123456789012345', 'utf8'); // sample key for encryption/decryption
    var keyAuth = Buffer.from('0123456789', 'utf8');      // sample key for authentication
    var ivLen = 16;
    var macLen = 32;
    var tokenBuf = Buffer.from(token, 'base64');
    var iv = tokenBuf.slice(0, ivLen);
    var mac = tokenBuf.slice(ivLen, ivLen + macLen);
    var ciphertext = tokenBuf.slice(ivLen + macLen);

    // Authenticate
    var hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', keyAuth);
    hmac.update(ciphertext);
    var macCalc = hmac.digest();

    if (macCalc.equals(mac)) {

        // Decrypt, if authentication is successfull
        var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv("AES-128-CBC", keyDec, iv);
        var decrypted = decipher.update(ciphertext, '', 'utf-8');
        decrypted += decipher.final('utf-8');
        return JSON.parse(decrypted);
    } else {
        console.log("Decryption failed");
    }
}

var token = decode('U3pukkS48yeNpsusv43Tmv2AmmDfYVtQ8jPw2izEQ0CVOfutGtA9e3ZWXJo2Ibi2axo31blnW6uq/yCz/KRSltwGhCmwpiHQ8mP5ulMf0Nr9V9Gzr6r+R6y3ZOpzTsV9IEkaKDxZTihfoDAzeyN9LYKS9uUW6URL0Do1HGaZ51o='); // from PHP code
console.log(token);
```

Here, the ciphertext was generated with the posted PHP code using the sample keys `0123456789012345` and `0123456789` for encryption and authentication, respectively.

I am suspicious of the `json_encode()` in the PHP code for decryption. Here I would expect a `json_decode()` and thus, in the NodeJS code a `JSON.parse()` (but you can modify this as needed).

Comment: Thats it, thank mam, you saved my day and my sanity, very very thank you :)